# Perl: Device::USB doesn't pass the tests

Tags: linux, usb, opensuse, perl, module

How could I find out the reason for the failing?

make test:

> PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/local/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
>   t/00-load.t ....................... 1/1 # Testing Device::USB 0.35, Perl 5.014000, /usr/local/bin/perl
>   t/00-load.t ....................... ok
>   t/01-create-usb.t ................. Failed 2/2 subtests
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Test Summary Report
>
> t/01-create-usb.t               (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
>     Non-zero wait status: 11
>     Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.
>   ...
>   ...
>
> Result: FAIL
>   Failed 16/22 test programs. 0/38 subtests failed.
>   make: *** [test_dynamic] Fehler 255

When I ran this script I get a `Segmentation fault` message (Speicherzugriffsfehler):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Device::USB;

my $usb = Device::USB->new();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of libusb do you have? There seems to be a ticket open on the module that decribes a problem similar to yours: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=65908

RT tickets open on a module are linked from the main search.cpan.org page for the module, here  http://search.cpan.org/dist/Device-USB/ It is often worth having a look at the queue if you're having problems with the module.

Comment: Installing an older libusb-version worked. Is this an openSUSE-specific problem or does the new version not work because the last module-update is from July 2010?

Answer (score 2):

1. [`perl -d:Trace ...`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aTrace) to find the failure point within the Perl code.
2. A tool like `strace` to find the failure point at the system call level.